# property 'prototype' is a read-only and non-configurable data property on the proxy target but the proxy did not return its actual value

Tags: javascript, typescript, vuejs3, es6-proxy

I want interception object with proxy，but I can’t understand why I report an error

```js
function createReactiveObject(target) {
      if (!isObject(target)) {
        return target;
      }
      return new Proxy(target, {
        get(target, key, receiver) {
          const result = Reflect.get(target, key, receiver);
          if (isObject(result)) {
            return createReactiveObject(result);
          }
          return result;
        },
        set() {
          return false;
        }
      });
    }
```

```js
    const obj = {
      a: {
        t: 1
      }
    }
    const testObj = this.createReactiveObject(obj);
    console.log(testObj.constructor.prototype);

// "TypeError: 'get' on proxy: property 'prototype' is a read-only and non-configurable data property on the proxy target but the proxy did not return its actual value (expected '#<Object>' but got '#<Object>')"
```

I want to know why And how to avoid this